# Where can I find a "stable" or "release" version of the MVC Mini Profiler source code?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I downloaded the MVC Mini Profiler source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler), compiled it, and integrated it into my company's website.

However, I've started noticing a couple of bugs, which made me realize that I didn't download any particular "stable" or "release" version -- I just downloaded the latest, in-development version from GitHub.

So now, I'm trying to figure out if there's a stable version that I can download, but nothing is mentioned on the GitHub nor the Google Code repos!

As I understand it, there is a NuGet package that can be used to grab the latest "release" binaries.  However, I require the source code, because I have a couple of modifications I'm making to the source.

Does anyone know how to find the latest stable version?  What version does StackOverflow use?

**EDIT**: I previously mentioned that I was implementing .NET 3.5 support, but that's completely unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a specific pin, however!

SE Inc. is currently using a build from (checks repo) Wed Feb 22. This ties in with [2.0.0-rc1](http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/2.0.0-rc1). Therefore, I think we can conclude that 8325ee327870 is the commit you want, although the next two (397592adda97 and c6f8413a4727) look innocuous.

Comment: Thank you.  
I continued researching, and started seeing the "Version X" commits, but I wasn't sure if that meant "Version 1.9 is here" or "Version 1.9 is starting".  I was looking for a tag, or branch, or a download, or something that "officially" marked a version number.

Comment: Also, I'd like to mention that it was pretty easy to create a .NET 3.5 compatible version.  I cannot share the code, because I'm at work, but I just wanted to mention that it's possible, and might take 2~3 hours, and it's beautiful once it's up! :)

Comment: @Scott as another reply mentioned, I *think* that's already in the works

Comment: I didn't realize it was **implemented**, I just thought it was a *feature request*.  That might help me keep up-to-date with the current version!

Answer (score 1):

MVC Mini Profiler requires .NET 4.0 so if you are using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5 you are out of luck. There has been a [request](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=37) to port it to .NET 3.5 but AFAIK there's no stable version for .NET 4.0 that hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Well, that's why I downloaded the source code.  It was pretty trivial to adapt the code to work with .NET 3.5, so there's no problem there.  The only problem is that I cannot find a version of the source code that is a "stable" version.  Does a .NET 4.0 "stable" version exist?

Answer (score 1):

There's a current pull request open on Github that seems to be full support for .net 3.5

Maybe that will be useful to you...

https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/pull/9

Comment: I just want to know what version of the code is "stable" -- the version that StackOverflow uses.  I want this to go into production, so I don't want a partially-finished fork -- I want to know what version is the latest stable release.

Comment: I didn't realize it was **implemented** ... I just thought it was a *feature request*.  Thanks for this reference!